# kubernetes /var/logs/ keeps growing unbounded

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I recently had a kubernetes cluster crash because /var/log/syslog and /var/log/daemon.log got very large (totaling over 14 Gb). I see that the logging specifications are set up in /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog, but I could not find a kops configuration setting that would limit these sizes. Is there such a configuration? Or is there a better way to limit the size of these logs? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would probably make for a nice feature request in the [kubernetes/kops repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops).

You can workaround this for now with [rsyslog log caps](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/log_rotation_fix_size.html).

Comment: Thank you very much @cmluciano!

Comment: @HeronAlgoSearch, if this answer covers your question sufficiently, please accept the answer. You can change your mind later if need be. Pertinent documentation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.

Comment: I wanted to test it out first. Once I have a working solution, will be glad to put it as an accepted answer.